# Classifying powerlines in LiDAR using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, lidar, 3d-analyst

I have a LAS dataset that includes powerlines. The dataset is unclassified, but I have access to a feature class that includes the powerlines as lines.

Is there a tool or method in ArcGIS Pro that lets me classify the points as powerlines and still lets me keep the other points?

I have access to 3D analyst.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Desktop available to you if the Pro doesn't have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the *Set LAS Class Codes Using Features tool*. Filter the LiDAR points for non-ground or even first return. The tool will intersect your LiDAR points with your 2D power line feature class. Barring that you could also use the Classification tab->Reassign Classification tool to interactively change the class codes. 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/las-dataset/edit-las-file-classification-codes.htm